# how to prevent multiple pg_dump to execute at the same time

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-dump

I am exposing a REST API to backup a Postgres DB. I have few questions related to that. I have seen most of these questions floating around google but could not find any suitable answer

1. Is there any way to know the status of the pg_dump? I can redirected the verbose log to the user but somehow I am not convinced with that.
2. Is there any way to know that a "pg_dump" session is in progress so that I can prevent the user from re-triggering?

Answer (score 1):

You could check if there is running `pg_dump` process by looking at the `pg_stat_activity` and also the state of the process:

```
SELECT 
    pid,
    datname,
    usename,
    state
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE 
    application_name = 'pg_dump';
```

It would be better if you could also lock some file with your script when you are starting `pg_dump` and check the lock status of that file when starting new `pg_dump` to avoid re-triggering.